# PHP alternative syntax not working properly

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've spent a few hours wrestling with this but still baffled. I have a simple if else statement like this:

```
    <?php foreach($authors as $author): ?>
    <?php if (!$authors): ?> 
    <p>No authors found</p>
    <?php else: ?>              
    <p><a href="<?= base_url('pages/author/'.$author->id); ?>"><?= $author->name; ?></a></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

$authors is the result of a database search (using Codeigniter query builder class although I don't that is relevant) and is therefore I believe an array of objects. If it finds data the code works fine. However if the search returns nothing, the 'No authors found' does not show. A var_dump of $authors after a nil search gives:

```
    array (size=0)
     empty
```

I have also try to write the if condition as:

```
(!isset($authors))
(empty($authors))
($authors == null)
```

but nothing works.
Grateful if anyone can suggest what is going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if(!$authors)` should go before the `foreach` loop, i.e. put the `foreach` loop inside the `else` block, like this:

```
<?php if (!$authors): ?> 
 <p>No authors found</p>
<?php else: ?>             
 <?php foreach($authors as $author): ?> 
 <p><a href="<?= base_url('pages/author/'.$author->id); ?>"><?= $author->name; ?></a></p>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

In your original example you tested the emptiness of the `$authors` array in each iteration of `foreach`, but since `foreach` does not iterate on empty [`iterable`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.iterable.php)s, the code is never reached. You want to test the emptiness *before* trying to iterate and only once, for that matter.

And although I believe `!$authors` should work for empty arrays, I'd probably use `empty($authors)` or `count($author) == 0` or something similar, to be more explicit, but that's just a personal preference.

Comment: Thank you, thank you! Of course that worked perfectly and I should have seen it - I wonder if there is a condition called 'code-blindness' after spending too long at the terminal!